# Address bind error in grpc server in springboot service

Tags: netty, grpc-java, app-startup

I'm unable to run my springboot service (gradle) as it fails during startup while trying to connect to a grpc server.
Earlier my service was on grpc version 1.24.0, updated it to 1.27.1.

Function to connect to grpc server -

```
    public static ManagedChannel getGrpcChannel(String host, int port, String serviceConfigJson) {
        return NettyChannelBuilder.forAddress(host, port)
            .enableRetry()
            .defaultServiceConfig(GrpcUtils.getServiceConfig(serviceConfigJson))
            .usePlaintext()
            .build();
    }
```

Getting below exception -

---

> 

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled. 
2022-12-23 16:54:54 [] ERROR [main] o.s.b.SpringApplication [SpringApplication.java:826] Application run failed 
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'shadedNettyGrpcServerLifecycle'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to start the grpc server
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:894)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.test.SampleApplication.main(SampleApplication.java:37)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to start the grpc server
    at net.devh.boot.grpc.server.serverfactory.GrpcServerLifecycle.start(GrpcServerLifecycle.java:51)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServer.start(NettyServer.java:249)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:184)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:90)
    at net.devh.boot.grpc.server.serverfactory.GrpcServerLifecycle.createAndStartGrpcServer(GrpcServerLifecycle.java:90)
    at net.devh.boot.grpc.server.serverfactory.GrpcServerLifecycle.start(GrpcServerLifecycle.java:49)
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:461)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:453)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:222)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:132)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:551)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1346)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:503)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:488)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:985)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:247)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:344)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:510)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:518)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1044)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

---

My service was working until earlier on local. This is what I've tried so far -

1. I have checked for netty default port and checked all listening ports as well. Didn't find any process that would block the grpc server startup.
2. Tried downgrading and upgrading the version of grpc libraries that I'm using.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

`Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use` gives a clear indication of what the problem is. There is another program using the server port your gRPC server is trying to bind to. Use `netstat -np` to find out the program using that port.